# Facing problem while updating fields in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching values of occupied beds and available beds which are fetched. Now, I want to update these values in database by adding 1 bed to available beds and subtracting 1 from occupied beds. But while updating these, 2 times values are getting updated.

For ex: occupied beds= 1

```
    available beds= 6
```

Expected Output: occupied beds=0

```
             available beds=7
```

Actual Output: occupied beds=-1

```
           available beds=8
```

Before update query

[image]

After update query

[image]

```
$q2 = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT available_beds,occupied_beds from section_master where section_id=3 AND del_flag=0");
           $q2->execute();
 
           $p1=0;
           $p2=0;
           
         if($q2->rowCount())
          {
            while($row21=$q2->fetch())
            {
             
              $points1=$row21["occupied_beds"];
              $points2=$row21["available_beds"];
              
              
              $qry_res2 = $dbConnection->prepare("UPDATE section_master SET occupied_beds='$points1'-1 , available_beds ='$points2'+1  where del_flag=0  AND section_id=3");  
             $qry_res2->execute();
  
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show us your full table data?

Comment: Maybe remove the single quotes `'` from the query

Comment: What does `$q2->rowCount()` return? You run that `UPDATE` query in a while loop

Comment: `occupied_beds='$points1'-1` is clearly wrong - that would leave the `-1` entirely outside the quotes. The same holds true for `'$points2'+1`

Comment: $q2->rowCount() returns number of rows in select query